# Как программно установить вью посередине

Tags: objective-c

Вопрос касательно iOS 9. Есть `subview` на рутовом `view`, которое имеет форму квадрата от края до края. Как программно при смене оринтеции девайса, оставлять это `view` посередине от края до края?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо у `view` поставить autoresizing - все 4 margin сделать flexible:

swift

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin, .FlexibleTopMargin]
```

objC

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

либо после вращения вручную поставить вью по центру родителя

```
view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)
```

Comment: view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin; помогло! Спасибо большое!

Comment: добавил objC в ответ.